# JavaFX equivalent to fill_parent in android

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I´m using JavaFX scene builder now for the first time and I´m wondering if there is any fill_parent setting to let for example the menu bar always have the size of it´s parent, even if the window is rescaled by code.

Is there any appproach to have such a behavior in the designer?

Answer (score 1):

There is the function "Fit To Parent" that can be found by right-clicking on an element in a container. This function is not available for all containers, what container do you want to fill?

Comment: "Fit to Parent" is available for AnchorPane container only.